# Show if $(a,p)=1$ there is a unique inverse of $a$ modulo $p$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse, gcd-and-lcm

In a proof of Wilson's theorem, I read this identity and just wondered how to prove it:

When $1\leq a\leq p-1$, we have $(a,p)=1$, so there exists a unique $\overline{a}$ with $a\overline{a}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$

Why is this the case?

Comment: since $(a,p)=1$ there exists r,s ,integers that $ar+sp=1$ so $ar=1 (\mod p)$

Comment: Consider $a,2a,3a, \dots, (p-1)a$. These are distinct modulo $p$ (show), and all non-zero modulo $p$. So their remainders on division by $p$ travel, in some order, through the set $\{1,2,\dots,p-1\}$. In particular, for some unique $k$ in the interval $[1,p-1]$ we have $ak\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p$ is a prime, its divisors are $1$ and $p$. Hence, if any $1 \le a \le p-1$ is given, the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $p$ is $1$ (as the other divisor of $p$, $p$ is greater than $a$, and hence not a divisor of $a$). So $(a,p) = 1$.

If $(a,p) = 1$, there are $c,d \in \mathbf Z$ with $ca + dp = 1$, reducing modulo $p$, we get $ca \equiv 1 \pmod p$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $(a,p)=1$, there exist  integers $r,s$ such that $ar+sp=1$ (see [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)). So $ar\equiv 1 \pmod p$.

Comment: This doesn't show uniqueness. For uniqueness, $aa_1\equiv aa_2\,\Leftrightarrow\, a_1\equiv a_2$ mod $p$ is obvious enough.

Comment: yes.  $\bar r$ is unique.

Comment: @user31415 $\,\  ab\equiv 1\equiv ab'\,\Rightarrow b\equiv b(ab')\equiv (ba)b'\equiv b'\ $ (works in any commutative monoid)

Comment: sorry, I meant $\Rightarrow$, not $\Leftrightarrow$.